# Does the convergence of $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x) dx$ imply $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } xf(x) =0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, improper-integrals

Let $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Does the convergence of $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x) dx$ allways imply $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } xf(x) =0$?

Comment: No. Let $f(x) = \sin(x)/x$.

Comment: It doesn't even imply $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: <off topic> I really cannot understand why this kind of question gets upvoted here regularly, in this case even twice, and even after comments have been issued which show that no, it's not true (by rather obvious counterexample) and whoever asked this question did not (as the ballon help for upvotes requests) show any kind of research effort...but I guess this is just me.

Comment: The integral $$\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)\,dx$$converges.  And yet, $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sin(x^2)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Thomas I think you are right, but I also want to defend the questioner a little.  This type of question, although it may demonstrate a lack of experience, demonstrates a rather nice intuition.  Also, until you see the "rather obvious counterexample" it isn't obvious!  It's sometimes hard to find what you're looking for until after you've found it.  But again, I don't disagree with you.

Comment: @Jedediyah you see, I don't complain about the question and I think it's perfectly legit to ask such a thing here (and I do know there are people around here which disagree with this point of view). In particular I don't ask for downvotes or for closing the question, so there is no real need to defend the questioner. I just cannot understand the upvote(s) in this case.